# Deleting users from channel settings Discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a command where it will overwritepermissions in the channel settings, I have made it change the channel settings for the user but can not figure out how to delete the user from the channel settings. The code below is one of the ways I have tried to do this if you could please help me that would be very helpful thxs.

```js
let usr = msg.mentions.members.first();

    
    msg.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => { 
        channel.replacePermissionOverwrites({
            "overwrites": channel.permissionOverwrites.filter(o => o.id !== usr.id)
        });
        
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overwrites.delete()`:

```js
let usr = msg.mentions.members.first();
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
    const permOverwrites = channel.permissionOverwrites.get(usr.id);
    if(permOverwrites) permOverwrites.delete();
});
```